# Multiple Google Apps Script editor Add-ons can be published from a single GCP project?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-apps-script-addon

I am developing Google Apps Script editor add-ons internally for my domain, and want to privately publish few separate add-ons.
However, when I went through the steps to publish my first add-on,

- https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons
- https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-gsm

the G Suite Marketplace SDK panel on the GCP web console didn't show me a button like "add a new addon", as in the screenshots below. Does that mean only a single add-on can be published from a single GCP project?

[GCP web console -> G Suite Marketplace SDK -> Configuration menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d462w.png)

[GCP web console -> G Suite Marketplace SDK -> Publish menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw9En.png)

Answer (score 2):

If the editor add-ons are for same application (Docs, Forms, Sheets or Slides), yes, that means that you should use a different GCP project for each of your editor add-ons

Let say that your add-ons are Google Sheets add-ons. Since the G Suite Markeplace SKD configuration page only have a pair of fields for the project id and the corresponding version, it's not possible to use the same project for multiple Google Sheets add-ons.